# Error in leafletProxy: could not find function "startsWith"

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Following is my shiny code. I want this app to allow user to click on the map and in response (i.e., Observe event) to the click, I want the map to show the marker.

```
 library(shiny)
 library(maps)
 library(stringi)
 library(ggmap)
 library(leaflet)

 ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
   tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
   leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")
 ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

## Make your initial map
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet() %>%
  setView(lng = -4, lat= 52.54, zoom = 7) %>%
addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                 options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE))
})

## Observe mouse clicks and add marker
observeEvent(input$map_click, {
click <- input$map_click
clat <- click$lat
clng <- click$lng
text<- paste("Lattitude", click$lat, "Longtitude", click$lng)

proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
proxy %>% clearPopups() %>%
  addPopups(click$lng, click$lat, text) %>%
  addMarkers(lng=clng, lat=clat, popup = as.character(text), label = as.character(text))
})

})

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

I get the following error.

```
 Warning: Error in leafletProxy: could not find function "startsWith"
 Stack trace (innermost first):
 66: leafletProxy
 65: observeEventHandler [#22]
 1: runApp
```

Comment: What version of R are you using? And what version of `leaflet`? Running `sessionInfo()` should tell you.

Comment: R version 3.2.4 and for leaflet, the version is 1.1.0 (i.e., leaflet_1.1.0)

Comment: The problem is that `startsWith` first appeared in R 3.3.0. Looks like the minimum R version requirements documented in the package DESCRIPTION file is wrong.

Comment: Let me download the latest  version (3.3.3) and see if the problem still persist.

Comment: Yes, it works when you update the version and install the packages again

Comment: I added an issue to the project github: https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/413

Comment: Seems like the issue has been resolved but the fix has not been released on CRAN. Installation with devtools fixed the issue for me.